# Python: Broadcast 2D index array from argmin in a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D grid with different values, and apply argmin along axis=2 to it, to get the lowest value in third dimension. How can I now extract the actual value and not only  the index of the minimum value?

```
import numpy as np
input = np.random.normal(size=(30,40,10))
minvals = np.argmin(input,axis=2)

foo  = input[minvals]
```

Minvals give my the index along axis 2 for the minimum value as expected. I  expected, that foo gives my a 2D array with the actual minimum values, but foo is now a 4D array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `take_along_axis` mixed with `expand_dims`. See the `take_along_axis` [tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) for more details:

```
import numpy as np

input = np.random.normal(size=(30,40,10))
minvals = np.argmin(input,axis=2)
foo = np.take_along_axis(input, np.expand_dims(minvals, axis=2), axis=2).reshape(30,40)

# Verification
foo_2 = np.min(input,axis=2)
print('Good result!' if np.allclose(foo,foo_2) else 'Bad results')
```

Ouput:

```
% python3 script.py
Good result!
```